# Serialize JSON from List<T> and Show Values

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I have a list of a custom object with two properties that needs to be serialized into JSON. Here is the object:

```
public class IndexData
{
  public string ColumnName { get; set; }
  public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

I need the JSON for the List to be returned like this:

```
{ "IndexData" : [
    { "Column1": "Data1",
      "Column2": "Data2"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: @stringpoet, could you clarify where "Column1" and "Data1" come from? Are these the values from two instances of IndexData in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<IndexData> list = new List<IndexData>()
{
    new IndexData(){ColumnName="column1",Data="data1"},
    new IndexData(){ColumnName="column2",Data="data2"},
};

//Using Json.Net
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new {IndexData=list.ToDictionary(x => x.ColumnName, x => x.Data)});
//Using JavaScriptSerializer
var json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                new { IndexData = list.ToDictionary(x => x.ColumnName, x => x.Data) });
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for (I used the `JavaScriptSerializer`). Works great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
var indexdata = new IndexData();
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(indexdata);
```

OR `DataContractJsonSerializer`

```
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IndexData));
s.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
var json = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

You can use the `SerializeObject` call to simple serialize your object:

```
var list = new List<IndexData> {new IndexData {ColumnName = "Foo", Data = "Bar"}};

var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

`output` will then be set to

```
[{"ColumnName":"Foo","Data":"Bar"}]
```